# transmitting "[]" string to php driven backend

Tags: javascript, php

So theres a function which calls to backend which fetches all reservations in a certain timeframe and returns them to front-end. If there are no reservations in the respective timeframe, backend returns the string "[]". This data is then transmitted to backend again where I evaluate whether reservations exist or not. 
For this, I want to use the php function "empty()" in backend.
And the code there basically just looks like this

```
$allReservationsOrRequestsByUser = json_decode($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser);
if(empty($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser)){
  $overlapExists = false;
}else{
  $overlapExists = 
checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations($todayDate, 
$allReservationsOrRequestsByUser);
}

echo $overlapExists;
```

Now, I tried the above code both with and without decoding it before the if-condition. In both cases, "empty()" function always returns false, which shouldn't be the case when the array actually was empty. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no need to use `empty` here, simply `!allReservationsOrRequestsByUser` will do the same without needlessly suppressing error reporting.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser)` *after* `json_decode` and show us what you get…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to check if "[]" as empty. So it isn't empty as a string... You can convert it to a proper array before checking with empty() like...

```
$a = "[]";
var_dump(empty($a));
var_dump(empty(json_decode($a)));
```

that returns,

```
bool(false) <- Without Json decode
bool(true)  <- With Json decode
```

Comment: But I already do decode it before checking it?See my code above:
"$allReservationsOrRequestsByUser = json_decode($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser);"

After this, $allReservationsOrRequestsByUser should contain the array, shouldnt it?

Comment: yes it should, what happens if you var_dump($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser) ?

Comment: Im not using var_dump for debugging, instead im echoing the results to frontend and there i do console.log. However, if Im just echoing the $allReservationsOrRequestsByUser and then output it with console.log, then I get the unaltered "[]" string.

Comment: @JSONBUG123 *Do* a `var_dump`. Debug *directly*, not through three layers removed.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. My problem was that I did an unnecessary "JSON.stringify" on the front-end before making the respective call to backend. Through this the string looked like this

"[]"

So it DID contain the two quotation marks ^^ Thats why the whole thing couldnt work, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to check array data in array or object
e.g if fetched array contain

```
     if(empty($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser[0]['name'])){
         $overlapExists = false;
      }else{
       $overlapExists = checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations($todayDate, 
      $allReservationsOrRequestsByUser);
      }
```

if object then use this and name is your database table column name

```
      if(empty($allReservationsOrRequestsByUser[0]->name)){
        $overlapExists = false;
     }else{
       $overlapExists = checkForOverlapWithExistingRequestsOrReservations($todayDate, 
        $allReservationsOrRequestsByUser);
      }

     echo $overlapExists;
```